# Calculating Object code - SIC/XE

Tags: assembly, machine-code, sic

```
0000    SUM         START       0       
0000    FIRST       LDX         #0              050000
0003    LOOP        LDA         #100            010064
0006               +LDB         #TABLE2         69101790
```

How would I calculate the object code of

```
0003    LOOP        LDA         #100            010064(object code)
```

How do I obtain the result of 010064(object code)? I already know how to do the first part(010), but I am unsure how I am supposed to get the second part of 064.

Any help would be great!

Comment: 100 decimal is 64 in hexadecimal, isn't that what you are seeing?

Comment: >,<... I am so slow sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is immediate addressing in the displacement(12bits), the immediate value needs to be represented in hexadecimal form. Therefore

```
LDA #100 010_ _ _
```

064 is written in the blank space, as it is the hexadecimal form of the displacement(100).